# Can someone explain the error in this while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I'm a beginner programmer... and I can't figure out what the problem is in this bit of code I'm writing for a text adventure. All I want it do At the moment is let the user enter a command, and then it converts it to ALLCAPS and prints that out. It should output this:

```
What shall I do?
pie
Your raw command was: PIE
```

But instead, it outputs this:

```
What shall I do?
pie
PIE
```

...and then it freezes. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void command_case();

string userIn;
string raw_command;
int x = 0;

int main()
{
    while(raw_command != "QUIT")
    {
        cout << "What shall I do?\n";
        cin >> userIn;
        command_case();
        cout << "Your raw command was: " << raw_command << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void command_case()
{
    char command[userIn.size()+1];
    strcpy(command, userIn.c_str());
    while(x < userIn.size()+1)
    {
        if(islower(command[x]))
        {
            command[x] = toupper(command[x]);
            cout << command[x];
            x++;
        }
        else if(isupper(command[x]))
        {
            cout << command[x];
            x++;
        }
    }
    raw_command = command;
}
```

I think it may be a problem with the while loop in `void command_case()`, but I can't figure out exactly what that problem is. I'd appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: `char command[userIn.size()+1];` - variable length arrays are not legal in C++. This whole `strcpy()` business is pointless, since you can just use `userIn[x]` and the like.

Comment: Search the web for "c++ string transform toupper".  Either use `std::string` or `char *`; don't cross the streams unless you know what you are doing. (Quote from GhostBusters movie).

Comment: Btw. `std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(),str.begin(), ::toupper);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do something like

```
void command_case()
{
    for(int i =0; i<userIn.size(); i++)
    {
      userIn[i] = toupper(userIn[i]);
    }
}
```

then `cout<<userIn` in the main

Answer (score 1):

One too much:

```
while(x < userIn.size()+1)
```

Comment: Don't use while, for is safer. If you do use while, make sure that each execution of the body reduces the number of remaining iterations. A string has elements from 0 to length-1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the x variable in the command_case() function.

When x becomes 3 (and "command[x] points to the null character at the end of "pie")
neither islower(command[x]) or isupper(command[x]) are true.

Neither section of the if statement executes, so x stays at 3 forever.
Since "userIn.size()+1" is 4, and x never reaches 4, the loop never exits.

A possible solution is remove the "x++" from both sections of the if statement, and have a single "x++" after the if statement.  This will increment x during every loop regardless of what character "command[x]" points to.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all cout calls from command_case() function. In fact the whole if-branch in the function is useless and you could just replace it with the following:

```
command[x]=toupper(command[x]);
```

For the simplicity you could replace the whole command_case() function with (just remember to `#include <algorithm>`):

```
std::transform(userIn.begin(), userIn.end(), userIn.begin(), toupper);
```